# How to check information in json is stored in redis database correctly?

Tags: redis

I have nodejs package. The package reads a message from a JSON file then retrieves devices and saves them to redis database which is running as a docker container. How to write integration tests in Python to verify that the devices in JSON file are stored at redis database correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Redis python package](https://pypi.org/project/redis/) to test with. I imagine the data is being saved in a hash in Redis. You can get all of the data using HGETALL:

```
import redis
r = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379)
r.hgetall('key')
```